# How does opa handle desktop versus mobile apps

Tags: opa

Mobile apps have specific gestures that are unique to them (e.g. long-press). As do desktop apps (e.g. hover).

How does one discriminate between these two user interfaces when writing an Opa program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Opa expert (I've never heard of it before your question) so I'm going off their Wikipedia page. But bear with me.

Opa is compiled to JavaScript with jQuery for client side execution. Therefore, it's no different than how any other web application would handle the different modes of interaction.

Typically, you write event handlers to handle both touch and non-touch events. Then you just respond to whichever event is generated on the client end.

Answer (score -1):

Opa currently lacks bindings to many mobile web events.

That said, it's quite easy to extend. [Here is a commit](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/commit/a171b9881371c32e34e64cbfe096d599dd8981d5) that adds a JS binding to the standard library for instance. Once you are familiar with this process, you are welcome to submit pull requests.